# SQL code for algebraic formula

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

[image: Want to calculate N from the formula]

How to solve 'N' for given EMI, P & R?

- P: Principal_amount
- R: rate
- EMI: EMI
- N: number of terms

Also:

```
id  principal_amount   EMI   rate 
 1    10000           5000   10.5
 2    32000           8000   9.5
 3    33000           9000   7
```

Need to calculate 'N' from the formula and have it in a table.

Expected:

```
 id   principal_amount   EMI   rate   N 
 1    10000             5000   10.5   calculate from formula
 2    32000             8000   9.5    calculate from formula
 3    33000             9000   7      calculate from formula
```

Comment: It appears that the first thing you need to do is solve for n.

Comment: Are you asking how to solve for `N` given `EMI`, `P` and `R`?

Comment: Yes. Exactly...

Comment: [How do I calculate tenure (N) from EMI formula if I know EMI, Principal (P) and Interest rate (R)?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-calculate-tenure-N-from-EMI-formula-if-I-know-EMI-Principal-P-and-Interest-rate-R/answer/Sundar-Balakrishnan)

Comment: i have my rate = 0.2099 ,principal_amount =10,000 , EMI =250 .  It gives me an error when i execute the code ..select log(1 + 0.2099, 250 / (250 - 10000 * 0.2099 ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just arithmetically solve the equation against N and use standard `log` function to get the algorithm:

```
select log(1 + rate, EMI / (EMI - principal_amount * rate )) AS N
  from my_table;
```

Comment: Nice math! I just went step by step to check it, and you're good.

Comment: i have my rate = 0.2099 ,principal_amount =10,000 , EMI =250 .  It gives me an error when i execute the code ..select log(1 + 0.2099, 250 / (250 - 10000 * 0.2099 ))

Comment: @user8545255, the result of `250 / (250 - 10000 * 0.2099 )` is a negative number. Logarithm is defined only for positive arguments. Actually there must me an inconsistency in the data, in other words, there is no real values for `N` (terms) to gain `EMI = 250` having `rate = 0.2099, principal_amount = 10,000`