# Have to implement algebraic equation in C# code

Tags: c#

I have one algebraic formula to calculate SJM factor, but I did not understand how can I implement this in my C# code.

The formula is as follows:

```
SJM Factor = S(J-M) / J(S-M)
```

Where I have values for SJM Factor, S & M and I have to calculate value for J.

Here is a detailed problem for this formula

[SJM Factor Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5LLR.jpg)

Here is a similar question which has the same problem : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51678023/sql-code-for-algebraic-formula/51678373)

Can anyone please show me how to implement this formula in C#?

Comment: This is more a math question than a programming question

Comment: Are you using webforms or mvc, also what data types are each of the variables in the equation?

Comment: @KlausGütter - Yes, but in my project i have to calculate this value to perform other operations

Comment: @SolaOshinowo - I'm Using ASP.NET MVC, their is Double Datatype for all these variables (SJMFactor, S, J, M)

Comment: You need to first have a formula(on paper) that calculates for J, then the formula can be used as a function in C#, if u can send the formula, i might send in a code

Comment: @SolaOshinowo - I have shared solution for this formula in Question. I have shared image for on paper solution for this formula.Please find   SJM Factor Calculation link in the question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question but simple maths

Comment: [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5LLR.jpg)

Comment: Please look at the two solutions others have given

Comment: @SolaOshinowo - yes its working. I don't have any knowledge about how can I convert these formulas for implementations. Can someone please give me any reference for how can I convert formulas like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iimplement the formula:

```
        float Factor = 0.9027f;
        float S = 100f;
        float M = 31f;
        float J = S * M / (S - Factor * (S - M));
```

Output J is 82.19825f.

Comment: Yes this formula works fine

Answer (score 1):

This is basic algebra:

```
J = -S*M / ((S-M)*SJMFactor - S)
```

Alternatively, multiply top and bottom of LNS by minus one:

```
J = S*M / (S - (S-M)*SJMFactor)
```

Comment: Also this formula gives correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Why not convert the formula to

[image]

as said above: it's the math's question

P.S.
And if, after all, you need mathematical transformations, you may look at NuGet package [MathNet.Numerics](https://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/MathNet.Numerics)